# zend setquery returns the same results for 2 different queries

Tags: zend-framework, gmail, google-api, google-calendar-api, gdata

im using the following code to retrieve events from google calendar.

```
$client = Zend_Gdata_ClientLogin::getHttpClient($user, $pass, $gcal);
            $gcal = new Zend_Gdata_Calendar($client);
            $query = $gcal->newEventQuery();
            $query->setUser('default');
            $query->setVisibility('private');
            $query->setProjection('basic');
            $query->setStartMin($date);
            $query->setStartMax($newdate);
            $query->setQuery(''.$key->name.'@email.com');
```

when the `$key->name`  gives 2 different strings.for example `george.s` and `george.r`...
the query `returns the same info`.it only happens to this query.others are working fine.and there are `no events assigned to george.s`.same info showed in george.r shows in george.s's info.

im using this code to retrieve events which has a particular person assigned to it.so thats why im taking the email as the query.

please tell me what am i doing wrong here?

Comment: I think your problem is in the way google handles the dot '.', the Api may consider the 2 strings as equal. Consider how gmail accounts use the '.' to build separate addresses to the same account. john@gmail would also get mail from john.tony@gmail. Functionally the same.

Comment: @RockyFord so how should i write my query? if this is not working,is there another way i could get what i want? please answer. thanks